# oozie : file and archive tag usage and differences?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

in oozie schema there are two tags for a java action , File and Archive .

`<xs:element name="file" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`
`<xs:element name="archive" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`

I am trying to understand usage of them ? I also noticed the both tags are also applied to a MR/pig action .

Answer (score -1):

Quick description about File and archive tags :

> The `file` & `archive` elements make available, to map-reduce jobs, files and archives. If the specified path is relative, it is assumed the file or archiver are within the application directory, in the corresponding sub-path. If the path is absolute, the file or archive it is expected in the given absolute path.
>
> Files specified with the `<file>` element, will be symbolic links in the home directory of the task.
>
> If a file is a native library (an '.so' or a '.so.#' file), it will be symlinked as and '.so' file in the task running directory, thus available to the task JVM.
>
> To force a symlink for a file on the task running directory, use a '#' followed by the symlink name. For example 'mycat.sh#cat'.

For more information about any oozie related documentation click on link     https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2_Workflow_Action_Nodes